# I'm getting an error from grid.after_idle() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1456, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\littl_000\Documents\Python\pd\PD GUI.py", line 185, in playmove
    grid.after_idle(automove(""))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 534, in after_idle
    return self.after('idle', func, *args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 516, in after
    self.tk.call('after', ms)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "after idle script script ..."
```

The code is just, grid.after_idle(automove(""))
It worked before but it was spaghetti code where I called a function within another function, the automove moves some dots on a grid ( lots of dots very quickly, its a maths problem) and I'm using the after idle so that the tkinter window doesn't crash when I try to move it even when this loop is running, it can take minutes. I have no idea what this error means however, and it doesnt seem to work when i use main.update_idletasks()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For instance, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

`after_idle` takes a *reference* to a function. When you do this:

```
grid.after_idle(automove(""))
```

... you are *immediately* calling `automove`, and the result of that function is what is getting passed to `after_idle`. The above is exactly the same as:

```
result = automove("")
grid.after_idle(result)
```

Most likely `automove("")` is returning `None`, which is why `after_idle` is throwing the error that it is throwing.

If you need to pass arguments, you can include them as additional arguments to `after_idle`:

```
grid.after_idle(automove, "")
```

Comment: This still causes tkinter to crash when the window is moved

Comment: If it immediately calls automove how do I make it wait until its idle and then call it

Comment: @EddieBaker: the answer tells you what to do. Give it the _name_ of the function.